# I'd like my script to interpret links when processing files

Tags: scripting

```
> ls -l aliasedname
lrwxr-xr-x  1 anon3202  users  19 Dec 25 05:24 aliasedname -> www/realfilename
```

I'd like for my script to return details about `~/www/realfilename` when it's fed information about `aliasedname` ($1) instead of the information about the link named `aliasedname` (what is shown above).

I think (maybe?) I want some type of `exec`?  But I'm really fuzzy on this.

I was contemplating doing an `ls`, a `cut` and evaluating it, then grabbing the last part to use as path... but it seems like that's a lot of work, and that there should be a simpler (more elegant) solution out there.

---

I'm doing a variety of things to $1 with my script, but anything can be passed to my script for processing.  I'd like to make sure I'm dealing with the actual file intended, and not with an alias.

I could just check to see if it's a file (`if [ -f $1 ]; then`) but if I'm passed an alias, it's pretty clear what the intention was, and I shouldn't just fail it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `readlink`? `man readlink` for details.

E.g.,

```
[/tmp]$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Jan 16 10:07 mylink -> test-link
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 16 10:07 test-link

[/tmp]$ readlink -f mylink 
/tmp/test-link
```

In response to your edit, you might benefit from "[File Test Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)"

> -h  file is a symbolic link

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'll first need to do a test to find out if `file` passed to script is `alias` or a `nonalias`, then use readlink on any aliases.  (correct?)

Comment: I think you're confusing the filename "alias" in your question with the shell builtin `alias`. In your question, "alias" is just the name of the symlink, and has nothing to do with the shell builtin `alias`.

Comment: I was unaware of `alias` I was using that as a generic phrase.  Let me rework my question.

Comment: readlink works on both files and aliases, and looks to be what I need in my scripts.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use readlink to resolve everything to an absolute path before starting doing things in every script? I mean, assuming that I don't want to do something to an alias.

Comment: `readlink` should suffice from what you've described

Answer (score 1):

If you need `ls` details use `-H (--dereference-command-line)` option:

```
ls -lH ./aliasedname
```